# Discrete convolution and supports: can we have $\operatorname{supp}(f * g) \subsetneq \operatorname{supp}(f) + \operatorname{supp}(g)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convolution, discrete-calculus

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. For $f,g:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ functions. Define their convolution in a point $x\in G$ as
$$(f*g)(x)=\sum_{y\in G}f(x-y)g(y)$$

From the definition of convolution is easy show that $$\operatorname{supp}(f*g)\subseteq \operatorname{supp}(f)+\operatorname{supp}(g)$$

When $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ denotes the set of points in $x\in G$ for which $f(x)\neq 0$, and with similar definitions with $\operatorname{supp}(g)$ and $\operatorname{supp}(f*g)$.

But, I spent a pair of hours trying to find functions $f$ and $g$ for which the equality does not hold in general. Since I do a lot of examples in finite abelian groups of the form $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and I always get the equality (is important remark the fact that I always use indicator functions), I'm interested in know examples in finite abelian groups for which the equality does not hold.

Any suggestion or example is welcome.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove tags tied to analysis/calculus themes due to the lack of limits, differentiation, and so on, and to make the title of your question more descriptive. It never hurts to make your titles descriptive, it will help both "viewership" (by potentially garnering more interest thanks to a unique yet adequate title) and future searchability, and you have a higher than enough character limit most of the time anyway. However, feel free to rollback or re-edit your post if you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $G := \mathbb{Z}/2n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \neq 0$. Let $A := \left\{\bar{0}, \bar{2}, \bar{4}, \cdots, \overline{2n-2}\right\}$ and $B := G \setminus A$.
Then, we can observe, using $1_C$ to denote the indicator function for any $C \subset G$ and $1$ to denote the constant function equal to $1$ on $G$, that:
$$\left(\left(1_A - 1_B\right) * 1\right)(x) = \sum_{y \in G} \left(1_A(x - y) - 1_B(x-y)\right) = \left|\left\{y \in G \mid x - y \in A\right\}\right| - \left|\left\{y \in G \mid x - y \in B\right\}\right|$$
Now, $G$, $A$ and $B$ were chosen in this particular manner in order to have the two cardinals be equal no matter the $x$ taken, hence the previous convolution is actually the zero function. Indeed, we can see that:

- $G = A \cup B$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $|A| = |B| = n$;
- If $x \in A$, then $x - y \in A$ iff $y \in A$;
- If $x \in B$, then $x - y \in A$ iff $y \in B$.

Hence:
$$\operatorname{supp}\left(\left(1_A - 1_B\right) * 1\right) = \emptyset \neq \operatorname{supp}\left(1_A - 1_B\right) + \operatorname{supp}(1) = G + G = G$$
and we have the desired counterexample.

Comment: Yesterday I read you solution and not find a mistake. Congratulations, your solution is very clear and concise. Thanks a lot for you example. I hope that also others members of the community can write down others solutions.